# Method in java to take array as parameter, copy first elements and then double the length?

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I essentially want a method that takes in my declared array and then copies the elements into a new array and then doubles the size with the remaining elements as 0. How can I make this possible? I am confused on the doubling of the array, I realize I can equal the array to the previous array to copy the elements.

```
 class Untitled 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int[] a = {6, 3, 5, 2};




}


public static int[] doubleSize(int[] j)
{
    int[] new = int [] j + int[] j
    return int[] j;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java automatically initialized the elements in an integer array as 0, so you don't have to do that manually.

```
public static int[] doubleSize(int[] j) 
{
    int[] newArray = new int[j.length * 2]
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = j[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

**Edit:** A more Java-esque solution is

```
public static int[] doubleSize(int[] j)
{
    return Arrays.copyOf(j, 2 * j.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. To create a new array with twice the length you can do:

```
int[] newArray = new int[j.length * 2];
```

Since the array is type `int`, each element will be initialized to 0.

So once you copy the elements from the old array you should be done.

Also, you will want to change your return statement to just

```
return newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you achieve required functionality in this way.

```
public class DoubleArray
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int a[]={2,3,4,5};

        int b[]=new int[2*a.length];

        b =Arrays.copyOf(a, b.length);

        System.out.println("DoubleArray.main()"+b);
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }

    }

}
```